# d opengl custom vs fixed-pipeline matrix weirdness

Tags: opengl, matrix, d

I have recently been working on shifting over to handling my matrix controls myself, so that my engine will be ready to shift over to a 4.0+ context, *though currently I am using a 2.1 context with Derelict*. I have tried all kinds of matrix calcs and nothing seems to work with my shader(nothing on screen except for FPS counter unless I switch back to fixed-pipe, or if I switch the vs to set gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);). Even when I grab the values that OpenGL normally sets and put them into it I get the same.

I added print out of both my matrix and the one that the fixed-pipeline returned to the draw calls and the output is IDENTICAL. I've already checked and double checked my shader code, so I'm pretty lost as to from where this bug is coming.

*This happens on both OSX and Windows. I have a `glGetError()` check every draw call and am not getting any errors. Shaders link and validate with out warning or error.*

## code for uniform loading:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelViewLoc,1, GL_FALSE ,modelview);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionLoc,1, GL_FALSE ,projection);
```

## Vertex Shader:

```
#version 120

//layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;

void main()
        {
                mat4 mvp = Projection*ModelView;
                gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position,1.0);
                //gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
        }
```

## Fragment Shader:

```
#version 120

uniform float slider;

        void main()
        {
                vec4 diffuse = vec4(vec3(slider),1.0);

                gl_FragColor = diffuse;
        }
```

## debug output:

Model 1:

```
OpenGL ModelView: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -2, -2, -8, 1]
mine:             [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -2, -2, -8, 1]

OpenGL Projection:[1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0002, -1, 0, 0, -0.20002, 0]
mine:             [1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0002, -1, 0, 0, -0.20002, 0]
```

Model 2:

```
OpenGL ModelView: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, -8, 1]
mine:             [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, -8, 1]

OpenGL Projection:[1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0002, -1, 0, 0, -0.20002, 0]
mine:             [1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.30323, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0002, -1, 0, 0, -0.20002, 0]
```

**UPDATE**I have released the code for matrix lib @ github.com/mclark4386/DMath See anything there?^^;

Comment: OS? GL implementation vendor?  Driver version?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code. Are you calling `glGetError()` to make sure nothing funky is going on?

Comment: I am indeed calling it every draw call. What part(s) of the code do you need to see? Be happy to give more info, I just didn't want to overload the post initially.

Comment: Please show the code where you supply the matrices to the uniforms. OpenGL expects you to do this! (OpenGL-2 provides standard uniforms, bound to the standard matrices, but those are called gl_Modelview, gl_Projection and so on. Your names are arbitrary.

Comment: What are you initialising OpenGL with? Derelict? Are you loading the correct OpenGL version for a 4.0 context?

Comment: @Bernard He doesn't need a GL4 context for his shaders. He just wants to be forward-compatible in respect to dropping fixed functionality and builtin uniforms.

Comment: @Matthew Quite unrelated comment: It is more efficient to write `Projection*(ModelView*vec4(position, 1.0))`, because that gives you mat-vec multiplication instead of a mat-mat multiplication. Actually you could also precompute mvp on CPU, but that would complicate your example too much.

Comment: I have released the code for matrix lib @ https://github.com/mclark4386/DMath See anything there?^^;

Comment: @MatthewClark I spent awhile chasing my tail over a similar problem (well, identical problem, but perhaps not identical cause) only to find (through the use of `glGetUniformfv`) that the matrices I was setting were not actually making it to the shader. In my case, I was stupidly invoking `glGetUniformLocation` before binding the shader program. Maybe try inspecting `ModelViewLoc` and `ProjectionLoc` (if they equal -1, the uniform was inactive when you fetched its location)?

Comment: @MatthewClark Also, in your matrix code, `loadFromQuaternion` seems to build the matrix in row major format (I may have just missed a transpose?), while OpenGL expects column major format. I don't know if that would cause it not to display, but it would probably cause some weird transformations. Also, should the last line of your scale function multiply by z? Thanks, by the way, seeing your code is helping me to get mine working.